# ¿Como puedo enlazar un textbox a una base de datos mysql desde visual studio 2010 c#?

Tags: c#

Hola soy estudiante de universidad y tengo un proyecto que trata de un punto de venta,tengo problema con enlazar un textbox con mi base de datos mysql, anteriormente enlace un combobox pero no se como enlazar un textbox, AYUDAAAAA
Enlace de combobox a mysql...

```
 string consulta = string.Format("select nombre from productos where tipo=2");
                //MessageBox.Show(consulta);
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
                MySqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();

                while (lector.Read())
                {
                    comboBox4.Items.Add(lector.GetString(0));

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si te entendí

pero creo que lo que quieres es alimentar con el resultado de tu SELECT un textBox:

```
while (lector.Read()){
    textBox1.text=lector.GetString(0);
}
```

ten en cuenta que si tienes mas de un registro en la respuesta a tu query el textbox solo se mostrara el ultimo.

Comment: ¿Como puedo evitar que se muestre el ultimo registro haciendo que aparezca lo que quiero?

Comment: siendo mas especifico en tu query, puedes por ejemplo acceder por un id unico de tal manera que solo te regrese un registro, asi el registro que quieres sera el primero y el ultimo...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con un datagridview
Imagino que ya tienes la conexión a la bd te lo resumo así, en este ejemplo funcional:

```
 Sub Filtrar2021()
        Try
            'If Check2021.Checked = True Then
            Dim command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;user=arch2021;password=miclave;database=clientes;Convert Zero Datetime=True;"
            conn.Open()
            Dim consulta As String
            consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE documento LIKE '" & Tbident.Text & "%'"
            oDataAdat = New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, conn)
                oDataset = New DataSet
                oDataAdat.Fill(oDataset, "clientes")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = oDataset
                DataGridView1.DataMember = "clientes"
            'End If
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("", "ok.")
            
        End Try
        
    End Sub
```

los texbox los llenas así:

```
 Private Sub SelectionChanged() Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged 'CellValueChanged
        
        Try
            'Dim celdas As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            Dim int As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            CbTipodoc.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(1, int).Value
            Tbident.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(2, int).Value
            TbNombreA.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(3, int).Value
            TbEmpresa.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(4, int).Value
            TBDetalles.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(5, int).Value
            DateTime.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(6, int).Value
            PictureBox5.ImageLocation = Me.DataGridView1.Item(7, int).Value
            TbNit.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(8, int).Value
            DateTimevence.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Item(9, int).Value
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("id").Visible = False
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("tipo").Visible = False
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("detalles").Visible = False
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("fechaV").Visible = False
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("nit").Visible = False
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns("cedula_imagen").Visible = False
            'labelColor()
        Catch ex As Exception
            '
            If Tbident.Text.ToString & TbNombreA.Text.ToString & TBDetalles.Text.ToString = String.Empty Then
                Log(DirDelLog, String.Format("Error  – ‘{0}'", ex.Message & vbFirstFourDays & ex.StackTrace), False)
            End If
            'End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

espero te sea util

Saludos